# Find eigenvalues of $A=kB$ by working only on $B$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

It may be a stupid question, but suppose you have a matrix $A=kB$ where $k$ is a constant and $B$ is another matrix. I need to calculate eigenvalues of $A$. Can I simply compute eigenvalues of $B$ and then multiply them for the constant $k$, or should I work on $A$ by multiplying every element of $B$ for the constant $k$ and then find eigenvalues?

Comment: If $Bv=\lambda v$ then $Av=(kB)v=k(Bv)=(k\lambda)v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as $k$ is nonzero, then $Ax = k\lambda x$ if and only if $Bx = \lambda x$, so your reasoning is correct.